# How to add % to the following preg_replace code and how it works

Tags: regex, url, preg-replace, friendly-url

this is the code

```
    preg_replace('@((https?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $s);
```

the problem here is it does not detect this url

```
    http://localhost:88/xyz%20abc/abc/Result%20Publication%20Page.php
```

although it detects the first %20 it does not detect the other ones at the end of the url.

sorry for this noob question. i searched but did not get specific answer.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Does every url to be matched start with `https?://` or does that have to be optional?

Comment: If you want to match the url you can use `(https?://)?\S+`

Comment: @Fede With `(https?://)?\S+` you match [almost everything](http://regex101.com/r/hA3dO6/1), that's why I asked :)

Comment: @Jonny5 yup, I know but OP uses it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `\` before the first dot.

```
((https?://)?([-\w]+.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wE4fI1/1)

OR

```
((https?://)?([-\w]+[.:%][-\w\./]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wE4fI1/2)

The first group contains the link you want.